# Expecting QUOTED STRING in pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have written a script to select from vsql:

```
LOAD 'sql://{select * from sandesh.insights_voice_day
    WHERE Observation_date BETWEEN '2011-11-22' AND '2011-11-23' AND
    Type='total'
    ORDER BY  Observation_date}'
```

It is showing exception as `'' Expecting QUOTEDSTRING?`. What is problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pig expects a quoted string following a load with the name of the file you are loading. Pig is not SQL, so you have to do something like first dump your query into a file and then:

```
A = LOAD "your_file" as (column1:datatype, column2:datatype);
B = FITER A by observation date > '2011-11-22' AND observation_date < '2011-11-23' AND
    Type='total';
C = ORDER B by observation_date;
DUMP C;
```

Now, this will order these as strings. So depending on the version of Pig you're using, you'll need to deal with timestamps with the appropriate function. Something like:

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/CustomFormatToISO.html

Comment: I don't know if `your_file` is appropriate because it looks like he is (trying) to load directly from SQL.  If he needs to dump the table to a file for your answer to work, you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be use of single quotes multiple times.  Following in a single line seems to compile (pig -c test.pig)

```
A = LOAD 'sql://{select * from sandesh.insights_voice_day WHERE Observation_date BETWEEN "2011-11-22" AND "2011-11-23" AND Type="total" ORDER BY  Observation_date}';
```